# IBM-Logging Plugin

Tags: 64-bit, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-plugin

I am trying to install the IBM-Logging Plugin using CF_CLI. However, I am facing the following error when running the executable:

```
Plugin requested has no binary available for your OS: windows, 386
```

My system is 64-bit.

Please help me.

Comment: What is the exact operating system that you are using? From where did you download the plug-in?

Comment: I tried on windows os.

Comment: i am trying to download from here "https://clis.ng.bluemix.net/ui/repository.html#cf-plugins"

Comment: I could download the plugin on MacOS using the following steps:

cf add-plugin-repo bmx-plugins https://plugins.ng.bluemix.net/

cf install-plugin IBM-Logging


@Mounika did you follow the above steps as well ?